# Vue.js and Computed Properties

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

Here is my code:

```
  <div id="app">
  <p>here is the message: {{message}}</p>
  <p>{{a}}</p>
  <p>here is the reversed message: {{reversedMessage}}</p>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello',
      a: 1,
    },
    computed: {
      reversedMessage: function () {
        this.a += 1;
         return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

First of all, why the value for **a** becomes **2**? I thought since **a** is before the computed property, it's value should be **1** and then in the next line and after calling the function for computed property, it's value would be **2**. Could you please explain this to me?

and second: in the chrome DevTools, when I change the value for **a** (like below):

```
vm.a = 8
```

in the **p tag**, the value for **a** becomes **a+1**. Why?! So every time I change the value for **a** in the DevTools Console, the value for **a** in **p tag** become **a+1**! why the function for computed property is called and changes the value for **a**?

Comment: `First of all, why the value for a becomes 2?` Because you add 1 to it. I have no idea what you mean by "before the computed property". The reason it's changing is because the computed property thinks `a` is used in  `reverseMessage`. You should not be altering data in `computed` properties.

Comment: @BillCriswell I mean I add 1 to a in the computed property and a is rendered before computed property. So I thought it's value should be 1.

Comment: It happens so quickly you'll never see one. If you remove `{{reversedMessage}}` from your template it'll stay `1`.

Comment: I'd read @Bert Evans solid answer.

Comment: @BillCriswell Thank you so much, this part of your answer: "The reason it's changing is because the computed property thinks a is used in reverseMessage. You should not be altering data in computed properties." was very helpful. thank you again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a` is defined in your data, it becomes a reactive property. That means anytime you change it, the change will be reflected *everywhere*. That's why `a == 2` initially in your text, because you `change` it in your computed value.

Secondly, if you change `a` in the devtools console, the `reversedMessage` will be *recalculated* because you reference `a` inside it. So the sequence is

1. Change `a` in devtools.
2. `reversedMessage` is triggered, because `a` is referenced inside it.
3. `a` now equals `a + 1`
4. Vue updates the DOM referencing `a`,  `<p>{{a}}</p>`

In summary, `a` is going to display it's current value everywhere you display it, and changing `a` via the console, causes `a` to be incremented.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I got it :)

Comment: @pershianix No problem :)